# WebStorm setup/configure eslint for React project

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, eslint

Using: WebStorm 2016.3

I'm getting all kinds of warnings from eslint after setting up a project using `create-react-app`.

The documentation is not clear on settings to use/ignore useful eslint warnings in my project.

Answer (score 1):

First setup/install: `npm i -D eslint babel-eslint` in your project

Then go into Webstorm Preferences > Language & Frameworks > Javascript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint

1. Set your ESLint package to point to either the current projects ...`/node_modules/eslint/` or some other directory where you have eslint installed via npm.
2. Make sure "Automatic search" is checked, this will use the `.eslintrc` file in your project directory
3. Create `.eslintrc` in your project directory root & add configuration:

```js
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {}
}
```